# how to insert white space between xml tags when database value is null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

This is part of xml file generated dynamically by php code.

The inner values of tags are fetched from database table and inserted in xml file dynamically.

When a field/column value is null or empty in database, the resulting xml tag looks as in case of 
     
 tag below.

```
 <Code>141113-0001</Code>
 <EntryDate>14-11-2013</EntryDate>
 <LabTestNo/>
```

and I get the following error on console

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined
```

My javascript code is this:

```
 xmlDoc=xmlht.responseXML;
 tableData=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data');
 document.getElementById('Code').value=tableData[0].getElementsByTagName('Code')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

How can I just insert empty space in text field using javascript, if a column is empty in database table and how to return white space between xml tags if a column is empty or null in table. So that the tag looks like

```
    <LabTestNo> "here comes the white space if column is null/empty" </LabTestNo>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use IFs ?

Comment: Convert this into code: `if(value is empty) { insert whitespace } else { insert the value }`

Comment: This solved my issue
I just used conditional operator to check for empty() and is_null() and if true inserted             "&#160;"
to displayed as empty space

Answer (score -1):

Here is no need to change the XML. Short/empty tags are valid XML and can be parsed. You can use Query Selector and Xpath expressions on the XML.

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined` is because you're trying to read the child node of an element without verifying that it exists (with `.childNodes[0].nodeValue`). You can use the `?.` object operator to avoid this.

Additionally the better property is `textContent`. It returns the full text content (including descendant nodes).

Combined you get something like:

```
const value = aDocument.querySelector(aSelector)?.textContent || 'default';
```

A little more specific:

```js
const xmlString = `<data><Code>141113-0001</Code>
 <EntryDate>14-11-2013</EntryDate>
 <LabTestNo/>
 </data>`;
 
const xmlResponse = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
 
const data = Array.from(xmlResponse.querySelectorAll('data')).map(
     (item) => ({
       Code: item.querySelector('Code')?.textContent || '',
       EntryDate: item.querySelector('EntryDate')?.textContent || '',
       LabTestNo: item.querySelector('LabTestNo')?.textContent || ''
     })
);
 
 console.log(data);
```